# Can we use "Two next sessions" here?

Tags: determiners, time, numbers

I wanted to ask my teacher not to teach one grammar in a session that I'm absent.

I have class Saturday/Monday/Wednesday

A) Imagine today is Wednesday

B) My teacher wants to teach that grammar in 2 sessions which is Monday

C) I want to ask my teacher to teach it in 3 sessions which is next Wednesday

> Could you not teach the grammar in the next 2 sessions and teach it(
>   leave it until) in  next 3 sessions?

How can I say this by saying number of sessions? (I don't want to use weekday names)

Comment: I'm curious why you don't want to use weekday names.  I'd have thought that would be clearer.

Comment: @rjpon because I want to able to replace "session" by other words too. Like in next two weeks or months etc.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use ordinal numbers to describe this to your teacher. So you are talking about the second and third sessions from today. You would only need to reference today once, as it would be assumed for the second reference. That would make your request:

> Could you not teach the grammar in the second session from today, and teach it in the third session instead?

A little more succinct would be:

> Could you teach the grammar in the third session from today instead of the second?

Comment: Thanks. It was one situation. Can I use this too. A) I want to come over to your home in 3 days B) can you not come in 3 days and come over 5 days from now?

Comment: That is a great clarifying question. I'm going to try to amend my answer rather than address it in a comment.